# Optimization of time-frequency distribution - OpenCL. Sequence of small FFTs

Tags: time, opencl, fft, frequency, analysis

Currently i'm trying to implement the time-frequency analysis on the ATI GPU device. Basically, what I need is to run FFTs within the small(256-ish) window moving through the initial array, and store the results of each calculation in a matrix [window_size, analysis_size].

I'm using clFFT library, with the following buffers structure:

```
data_buffer ~ complex<float>[analysis_size]

out_buffer ~ complex<float>[window_size * (analysis_size-window_size)]

in_buffers ~ overlapped window_size subbuffers within data_buffer, for each calculation

out_buffers ~ window_size subbuffers within out_buffer, for each calculation. No overlapping.
```

After the writing data(clEnqueueWriteBuffer) to the in_buffer(when all in_buffers should be filled) I simply run in a cycle the desired amount of clfftEnqueueTransforms with in_buffers[i], out_buffers[i] as parameters. After that I read everything from the out_buffer with a single clEnqueueReadBuffer.

All that bothering with subbuffers was supposed to decrease the data transfer overhead, but still...

IPP's implementation of FFT makes the same thing twice faster, which is sort of confusing. What am I doing wrong? Is there any possible optimizations, or maybe fundamental mistakes? Thanks for any help.

My code is available through [that](http://pastebin.com/EDuT6PqQ) link.

Comment: Launch clfftEnqueueTransform in non-blocking mode. If every launch takes small amount of time, and number of launches is big, blocking operations may produce significant overhead.

Comment: As it is said in the description of the clfftEnqueueTransform, "Enqueue an FFT transform operation, and return immediately (non-blocking)". It is designed to be non-blocking, and there's no usual way to change that behavior.

Comment: Small FFTs are not really well suited for GPU. Maybe that generates the slowdown?
Additionally: Due to the cycle properties of the FFT, I think there have to be much more efficient ways of doing what you are doing. Every new FFT only changes 1 sample with respect to the previous one. So maybe is better if you find a way of doing it cleverly on the CPU.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, now I'll try to make it more efficient mathematically. Idk if it will work, but totally worth trying.